# "On screen” in Spanish

Tags: vocabulario, gramática

How does one translate the phrase, “on screen” into Spanish? Is the below sentence an appropriate attempt?

> Por pudor nunca besaría **en la pantalla**.
>   <sub>Out of modesty, she would never kiss **on screen**.</sub>

Comment: I do not know how to translate out of modesty but you can drop "en" and put only "besaría la pantalla".

Comment: Won’t “besaría la pantalla” indicate “kissing the screen” itself instead of the intended “kissing ON screen”?

Comment: Now I have understood it. I thought you were saying to kiss on screen as to kiss directly over the screen, if it is an scene it is  different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct translation is

> Por pudor nunca besaría **en pantalla**

Comment: To expand on this, it is similar to english: en pantalla=on screen= while being filmed, en LA pantalla= on the screen=while on (top of?) the screen, literally

Comment: `en LA pantalla` note the `la`

Answer (score 3):

A literal translation of that phrase would depend of the context

If it's about a movie, the phrase would be changed to something more specific
Por pudor nunca besaría frente a las cámaras. Out of modesty, she would never kiss in front of the cameras.

If it's about kissing your screen(tv, monitor)
Por pudor nunca besaría la pantalla. Out of modesty, she would never kiss the screen.